# Navigation UISearchBar issue

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar

I am facing one issue in UINavigationBar with UISearchBar. The right button item overlay to search bar. I want to add left bar button on the left position of search bar. Please find image for understanding.
[image]

Please find some code here.

```
searchBar = SearchBar()
        searchBar.delegate = self
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            searchBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
        }
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
        navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
```

Comment: Please paste your code

Comment: Please check above code I added right button from Storyboard.

Comment: which iOS you are using?

Comment: I am working for  iOS 11

Answer (score 0):

You can use default `cancel` button for the search bar

there are some methods for cancel button:-

```
func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    return true
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

The Cancel button appears only when the user start entering characters in the field.

Comment: my question was how can I left and right button with search button without overlay button problem. Thanks